# ¿Como validar datos positivos?

Tags: java

Hola que tal estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje java y estoy ahora practicando arreglos, el problema es que quiero validar que solo me acepte numeros positovos ya se que la variable que inicializa para ingresar los datos debe ser mayor a cero pero nose donde poner la condicion, si dentro de mi ciclo for cuando ingrese los datos o donde? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comprueba que el numero que estas ingresando sea mayor a 0... Un if con `> 0` te hace el trabajo

Comment: pon tu codigo como texto

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y leas :  [ask] para que te podamos ayudar y evites votos negativos.

Answer (score 1):

tendrías que introducir la condición dentro del for. Te dejo una solución:

```
   package ejarray;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author ismae
 */
public class EjArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N;
        System.out.println("Introduzca el tamaño del array");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        N = teclado.nextInt();
        
        int [] array = new int[N];
        System.out.println("Introduzca los números del array");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "- ");
            array[i] = teclado.nextInt();
            if(array[i] <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Introduzca números positivos");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Número: " + array[i]);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```